# Only customize sign in part of User Journey in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are attempting to implement Azure B2C using Journey Framing to embed a custom SignUp/SignIn login box into an embedded iFrame on our website. After following Microsoft's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy, we are able to get the login to function correctly in the iframe. The issue is that we don't want the rest of the user journey (Sign up, forgot password, etc.) to show up in that iframe, but that is exactly what is happening.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc., you are running the "SignUpOrSignIn" user journey.

That's why you see the sign-up.

The sign-in Technical profile is "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email".

In the metadata, set:

```
<Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>
<Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">none</Item>
```

Comment: Except I still want those links to appear in the iframe as part of the sign-in. I just want them to open a new page upon click.